# Show/Hide dropdown list values from other dropdown list value changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Show/Hide some values of my ddlDuration that will change depending on the ddlLOanType I want. For example if they choose Personal Loan type from my dropdownlist, I want it to show all the values from the ddlDuration and if I choose New Car Loan, I want it to show these values "36,48,60". I'm not really sure what I should use for this. Thank you for your help

```
Type: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLoanType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlLoanType_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Personal Loan</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">New Car Loan</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Used Car Loan</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

Duration:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDuration" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlDuration_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="24">24</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="36">36</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="48">48</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="60">60</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: ddlLoanType_SelectedIndexChanged on this event bind your ddlDuration dropdown instead of show and hide the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  protected void ddlLoanType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (ddlLoanType.SelectedValue =="2")
            {
                ddlDuration.Items.FindByValue("12").Enabled = false;
                ddlDuration.Items.FindByValue("24").Enabled = false;


            }
        }
```

However this is not the correct approach to solve this issue , When writing a code you should not have any dependency and should be flexible enough to modification in future .What if some day logic changes than who is gonna add list items into your aspx page os some day bank decides to change duration??Try to bind your data with dropdownlist with some id which can recognize for which loan type what values will be shown in dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options, but you shouldn't start with the items hard-coded in your markup.

Quick solution:

Have a private `List<string>` variables set up for each of the collections of numbers (I say string instead of int because ListItems will be converted to strings).

So for instance,

```
private List<string> personalLoanIds = new List<string> () {"12", "24"};
```

When `ddlLoanType` is changed to Personal Loan, you can set your `ddlDuration`'s DataSource to `personalLoanIds` then call the `DataBind()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are already handling the ddlLoanType_SelectedIndexChanged event, all you need to do there is add/remove the values that apply/don't apply and rebind the data.

Here's an example:

```
protected void ddlLoanType_SelectedIndexChanged (EventArgs e)
{
       if(ddlLoanType.SelectedValue=="1") //show all
       {
           ddlDuration.DataSource=new int []{ 12,24,36,48,60 } ;
           ddlDuration.DataBind();
       }
       else if(ddlLoanType.SelectedValue=="2") //car loan
       {
           ddlDuration.DataSource=new int []{ 36,48,60 } ;
           ddlDuration.DataBind();
       }
}
```